# Stuck on a Homework using ArrayDeque and Threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraydeque

**This is my Question**

A health center has employed two doctors that examine and treat at most 25 patients in a day.
A patient is examined and treated by any one of the two doctors.  Each patient has to register his name so that the doctors can examine and treat the patient on first-come-first-serve bases.

Exercise 2
Part a: For the scenario2 mentioned above, develop a program that creates patients and doctors (both are threads). Patients register in a queue and the doctors pick patient from the same queue on first-come-first-serve bases and examine and treat them. Use the queue that is not thread safe (For example ArrayDeque). Make sure your program has no synchronization issues.

Part b: Use the queue that is thread safe (For example, ArrayBlockedQueue) and check if your solution has synchronization issues. (Make sure that you solution does not provide synchronized methods or synchronized blocks)

**This is my CODE**

```
package lab8;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;

public class LAB8 {
class Doctor implements Runnable {
    private String name;
    private Patient patient;
    Doctor (String n){
        name = n;
    }
    public void examine (){
        System.out.println("Doctor is now examining the patient");
    }
    public void treat(){
         System.out.println("Doctor is now treating the patient");
    }
    @Override
    public void run (){


        }
    }


static  class Patient implements Runnable {
    private String name;
    Patient (String n){
        name = n;
    }

    public void register(String name){
        System.out.println(name + " is registering in Queue");
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){       
         ArrayDeque<Patient> Patients = new ArrayDeque(25);
        for(int i = 0;i<25;i++){
            Patients.add(new Patient("Patient No " + i));
            Patients.removeFirst().register("Patient No " + i);
        }
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayDeque<Patient> Patients = new ArrayDeque(25);
    for(int i = 0;i<25;i++){
        (new Thread (Patients.removeFirst())).start();
    }
}
```

}

**This is the error I am getting when I run it.**

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.ArrayDeque.removeFirst(ArrayDeque.java:278)
at lab8.LAB8.main(LAB8.java:50)
Java Result: 1

I am only trying Part A right now.

Comment: Cool question. http://www.eaipatterns.com/CompetingConsumers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main function, the `Patients` ArrayDeque object has no Patient objects. Rather it is empty, so there is nothing to remove from the queue. You need to add some Patients first.

```
ArrayDeque<Patient> Patients = new ArrayDeque(25);
for(int i = 0;i<25;i++){
    (new Thread (Patients.removeFirst())).start();
}
```

You would need to add new Patients to the `Patients` ArrayDeque first like you do here.

```
Patients.add(new Patient("Patient No " + i));
```

So you have have something like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayDeque<Patient> Patients = new ArrayDeque(25);
    for(int i = 0;i<25;i++){
        Patient p = new Patient("Patient No " + i);
        (new Thread (p)).start();
        Patients.add(p);

    }
}
```

Comment: After implementing the above in the run() of Doctor and then making the Doctor thread in the main, my output is printed twice. Could you tell me why this is.

Comment: How do I show you my code again. This is kinda confusing :/

Comment: I think it is because you are registering Patients twice. Once in the `main()` function, another time in `Patient.run()`. Once you add `Patients` to the `ArrayDeque`. Start up the Doctor thread and inside `Doctor.run()` method, call `ArrayDeque.removefirst()` there. Let me know if that made sense.

Comment: I made 2 instances of Doctor() and therefore 2 threads are run, but I can't deque the patients. Hence, I find my Doctors treating the same patients; ie, something like this

**Doctor 2 is now examining the Patient No 0
Doctor 1 is now examining the Patient No 0
Doctor 2 is now treating the Patient No 0
Doctor 1 is now treating the Patient No 0**

Comment: That may be the point. `ArrayDeque` is not thread safe. Hard to tell though, without seeing your current code. One thing you can try is swapping out `ArrayDeque` with  a thread safe queue such as `ArrayBlockedQueue`. And see if you still have duplicates.

Comment: I wish I could show you my code, but I am new here and still learning how to post and I can't figure it out. Anyways, thank you so much for your time and effort on this problem. Thanks to you, at least I am able to output something :) +1

Comment: You can add here http://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/ and I will be happy to look at it. As well, please up vote :) Thanks.

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/NCPSEc0Q]

Please do look at it, I've noticed that if I keep only one doctor, the patients do everything once. But, if I keep it for 2 doctors then the methods are done twice. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your code, every time you create/start a Doctor thread, the `Doctor.run()` method will be executed. So if you start two Doctor threads, each Doctor thread creates it's own 25 Patients. You should move `ArrayBlockingQueue<Patient> Patients` to a global variable, so Patients and Doctors can see it. When you start a Patients, add itself to the `Patients` global queue. When you start the doctors, have them pop Patients off the queue.

Comment: WOOOH IT WORKS!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH :) I'LL UP VOTE YOU FOR SURE ONCE I HIT 15+ REP. YOU'RE THE BEST :)